# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'."

Tags: angular, typescript

what is the reason behind the issue >?

Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' on

<password-strength-bar [password]="registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.value"

#html code

```
<div class="form-group row" formGroupName="passwords">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password"
        [class.is-invalid]="registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.touched && registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.invalid">

      <password-strength-meter [password]="registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.value"
        (strengthChange)="onStrengthChange($event)">
      </password-strength-meter>

      <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.touched">
        <div class="text-danger"
          *ngIf="registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.touched && registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password.hasError('required')">
          Password is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

#code

```
public registerForm = this.fb.group({
    email     : ['', 
                [Validators.required, Validators.email], 
                [
                  // this.isEmailUnique.bind(this),
                  // DuplicateEmailValidator(this.apiService)
                ] //async validator(used as  in view)
              ],
    passwords : this.fb.group({
      password        : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      confirmPassword : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    }, {
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a getter for the `passwords` group in your .ts file.

```js
registerForm: FormGroup;

public get passwordsGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.registerForm.get('passwords') as FormGroup;
  }

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.buildForm();
}

buildForm() {
 this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    email     : ['', 
                [Validators.required, Validators.email], 
                [
                  // this.isEmailUnique.bind(this),
                  // DuplicateEmailValidator(this.apiService)
                ] //async validator(used as  in view)
              ],
    passwords : this.fb.group({
      password        : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      confirmPassword : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    }, {
  }),
});
}
```

then in HTML

```html
<password-strength-meter [password]="passwordsGroup?.get('password')?.value"
        (strengthChange)="onStrengthChange($event)">
      </password-strength-meter>
```

OR (should work, need to test)

```html
<password-strength-meter [password]="passwordsGroup?.value?.password"
        (strengthChange)="onStrengthChange($event)">
      </password-strength-meter>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at LoginComponent.get passwordsGroup [as passwordsGroup

Comment: I updated the answer, set your FormGroup on init and see if that helps.

Comment: I also added null check on the HTML side `?`

Comment: Sir , I would like to add one last help , I wanna implement a password checker sir like this one https://imgur.com/a/rm63auy , instead of meter Sir I wanna use a check icon and text , the default color is gray , for example 8 characters minimum is required when user type 8 characters the checkbox and text will be color green and so the rest of the checker like one upper case if user input upper case so on and so forth, I have my https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-i4uqtt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html sir but I am having trouble making it possible , maybe you can help me Sir. Thanks.

Comment: I just wanna replace the meter Sir with check box

Comment: This is better suited as a new question as it pertains to more than just setting up FormGroups.